# Table of run times stored as strings converted to values manipulated and converted back

Tags: string, vba, excel, type-conversion

I keep a running log in an excel worksheet that is part of a larger exercise workbook. I am trying to set up the worksheet so I don't have to manually do the math every time I enter a new run. I enter the and want the worksheet to calculate the unfinished lap for me (the portion of the run after the last mile that my runners watch won't give me a lap time for, say .25 miles) I am using an odd notation for the times which I would be willing to change if necessary but I am most concerned with it being readable so I don't want to change it to something that makes the excel work easier but bothers me when I am looking through my runs.  Here is a what it looks like:

```
Date  Distance  TotTime  Avg Time  1      2      3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  UnfinLap
10/2  2.3 mi    19'35"   8'31"     8'28"  8'53"                           2'14"
```

What I want to do is for each cell in the UnfinLap column I want it to convert the total time into a value, convert and subtract each lap time, then finally convert it back into a string in my chosen format. And the runs vary in length so a 5.2 mile run would have 5 columns with values. I have neither a large amount of experience with excel or VBA but I am pretty quick to learn and have some programming experience so I took a shot at creating a macro for this without much success.

```
Sub Lap_Time_Function()
'
' Lap_Time_Function Macro
' This converts the times to value, does the math then converts back
'
    ' Variable Declarations
    Dim TotMins As Integer
    Dim TotSecs As Integer
    Dim LapMins As Integer
    Dim LapSecs As Integer
    Dim LoopCounter As Integer
    Dim UnfinishedLap As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ' Initial values set
    LoopCounter = 7
    TotMins = WorksheetFunction.Value(WorksheetFunction.Left(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2), 2))
    TotSecs = WorksheetFunction.Value(WorksheetFunction.Mid(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2), 4, 2))
    wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ws = wb.Sheets("Run Log")

    ' Calculate time of unfinished lap by subtracting current finished lap from total time
    Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, LoopCounter))
        LapMins = WorksheetFunction.Value(WorksheetFunction.Left(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, LoopCounter), 2))
        LapSecs = WorksheetFunction.Value(WorksheetFunction.Mid(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, LoopCounter), 4, 2))
        TotMins = TotMins - LapMins
        TotSecs = TotSecs - LapSecs
        LoopCounter = LoopCounter + 1
    Loop

    UnfinishedLap = CStr(TotMins) & CStr(Chr(39)) & CStr(TotSecs) & CStr(Chr(34))
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 17) = UnfinishedLap

End Sub
```

If there is a simpler solution or anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need VBA at all.

Excel formula to convert from `m'ss"` (in `A1`) to Excel time:

```
=TIMEVALUE("0:"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"'";":");"""";""))
```

Excel formula to convert from Excel time (in `B1`) to `m'ss"`:

```
=TEXT(B1;"[m]'ss")&""""
```

Using such functions, you can do arithmetic with Excel times.

Comment: I have to mess around with this to account for the fact that my runs have different lengths (ie. one run might be 6.2 miles and have info in 6 columns another might be 2.3 and only have two columns worth of info) But this has definitely pointed me down the right path. This is a much easier solution, thank you. Unfortunately I know far too little about how to use excel and I'm constantly trying to do things with it that I know can be done but I refuse to give up trying to figure out a solution. Thanks again!